# Why does windows mobile 6 emulator restart after each new deploy?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-debugging, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-5.0

When I stop and re-run the debugger in Visual Studio against a Windows Mobile 6 device, the emulator restarts each time making the debugging experience extremely slow.  I could understand if I made changes to the code, but this is happening regardless of whether changes are made.

Is there any reason why Visual Studio would restart a new emulator each time? How can I ensure that the debugger uses the same instance of the emulator that is already running?

Comment: Try to detach debugger instead of stop it.Or close debugged application normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had multiple projects within the solution for various assemblies and the emulator type set for each project was sometimes different and thus causing multiple emulators to fire up.  When I closed the multiple emulators Visual Studio would then re-start them all next time I went to debug.